# Delta distribution as an integral...

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

Hi,
I'm actually physics student and I've not been able to understand how the following integration has been performed:

> [...]
>
> The fields e and A have support on these discrete structures. The $su(2)$-valued 1-form
>   field $e$ is represented by the assignment of an $e \in su(2)$ to each 1-cell in $\Delta$. The connection
>   field A is represented by the assignment of group elements $g_e \in SU(2)$ to each edge in $\mathcal{J}_\Delta$
>
> The partition function is defined by
>
> ${\cal Z}(\Delta)=\int \prod_{f \in {\cal J}_{\Delta}} de_f\prod_{e \in {\cal J}_{\Delta}} dg_e e^{i {\rm Tr}\left[e_f U_f\right]}$
>
> where $de_f$ is the regular Lebesgue measure on $R^3$,
>   $dg_e$ is the Haar measure on $SU(2)$, and $U_f$
>   denotes the holonomy around faces, i.e., $U_f=g^1_e\dots g^{N}_e$ for $N$ being the number of edges bounding the corresponding
>   face. Since $U_f \in SU(2)$ we can write it as $U_f=u^0_f\ {{1}} + F_f$ 
>   where $u^0_f\in C$ and $F_f \in su(2)$. $F_f$ is interpreted as 
>   the discrete curvature around the face $f$. Clearly ${\rm Tr}[e_f U_f]={\rm Tr}[e_f F_f]$.
>   An arbitrary orientation is assigned to faces when computing
>   $U_f$. We use the fact that faces in ${\cal J}_{\Delta}$ are
>   in one-to-one correspondence with $1$-cells in $\Delta$ and label
>   $e_f$ with a face subindex.
>
> Integrating over $e_f$, we obtain
>
> ${\cal Z}(\Delta)=\int \ \prod_{e \in {\cal J}_{\Delta}} dg_e \prod_{f \in {\cal J}_{\Delta}}{\delta}(g^1_e\dots g^{N}_e),$
>
> where $\delta$ corresponds to the delta distribution defined on
>   ${\cal L}^2(SU(2))$.
>
> [...]

The details are not important, what I need to understand is how the integration over the $e_f$'s has been performed

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whoever performed that integration is using the following fact from Fourier analysis:

The "delta function supported at the position 0" is the Fourier transform of the constant function 1.

$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1 e^{ikx}dk$

You can prove this by approximating the delta-function with a sequence of Gaussian bump functions.  Fourier transforming Gaussians inverts the variance, so as the Gaussians approach a "delta function spike", their Fourier transforms approach a constant.

Comment: I know this fact; that the delta function is the Fourier transform of 1, but what bothers me here is that I have a trace in the exp!

Comment: Trace defines a non-degenerate inner product on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

Comment: So the expression on the exp is like a product of two elements in $\mathfrak{su}(2)$??

Comment: a sum of products, yes.

Comment: Merci beaucoup :-)